# Speed - Powerpoint shortcuts

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint

I was wondering whether someone can help me with the following issue. When trying to access keyboard shortcuts in powerpoint in stepwise fashion, (e.g. when I press Alt R to go to access review menu, in the aim to subsequently perhaps press a next second level shortcut, etc...), then there is a significant delay in powerpoint as it bit by bit in a staggered and slow manner displays the shortcut symbols (delay of around 2 seconds before all shortcut icons are displayed). is there a way to avoid this / accelerate this?

many thanks -Wouter

Answer (score 0):

Whether I press Alt+R then C or Alt+RC, as fast as I can, I get the desired result of inserting a comment.  I don't see that it's necessary to wait for the tooltips to appear.

In this case I'm using PPT 2010.